# Java: For loop: can not be resolved to a variable error

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

When I try to compile this code, I get an error saying:

> `i` cannot be resolved to a variable

What I´m doing wrong? How can I fix it?

```
boolean[] onibusDoTrajeto(int trajeto1, int trajeto2){

  boolean[] lugaresNoTrajeto = new boolean[49];

    for(int j = 0; j < _assentos[0].length; j++) {
      for (i = trajeto1; i <= trajeto2; i++){

        if (_assentos[i][j] = true){
         lugaresNoTrajeto[j] = true;
         break;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing "int" before your i.

Comment: =/ I´m so sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Not at all! Happens to everyone (:

Comment: @Karan Yes, I did;  the question is on its way to getting closed as a typographical error.  I meant to suggest that OP delete, but Hovercraft is right, it's got an upvoted answer, so it can't be deleted.  I should read more carefully all around.